# Rails 4: using a js.erb file as a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to define a `.js.erb` file as a partial? I have several `.js.erb` that have code that could just be moved to a common file like a partial, and then I would just call render on it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same rules as normal partials: name the file beginning with `_yourfile.js.erb` and in your main file call it with `<%= render partial: "yourjsfile" %>`

Although, being javascript a programming language, you might want to think to refactor your code instead of resorting to this